# How to create a DELETE route and its function with a FORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

This is the error im getting

> No route matches [POST] "/questions/1"

This is the controller code
I am trying to get the question to be deleted when using the button
I know that the route is /question/:id and the method is POST and the method name needs to be destroy

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

def index
@questions = Question.all
end

def show  
id = params[:id]
@question = Question.find(id)
@answers = Answer.all
end 

def destory 
@question = Movie.delete(params[:id])
redirect_to "/questions"
end 

def create 
Question.create(title: params[:title], content: params[:content])
redirect_to "/questions"
end
end
```

This is the html the form is the delete form

```
<div>
Title:<br>
<%= @question.title%><br>
Question:<br>
<%= @question.content%><br><br>
<form action="/questions/<%=@question.id%>" method="POST">
<input  type="hidden" name="method" value="DELETE">
<input type="submit" value="Delete Question">
</form>

<% @answers.each do |answer| %>
<% if answer.question_id == @question.id %>
Title:<br>
<%= answer.title%><br>
Answer:<br>
<%= answer.content%>
<%end%>
<%end%>  

<form>
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"><br>
<input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Answer">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :questions
end
```

Comment: What is that? `erb` plus some hand-crafted HTML? Why aren't you using a form helper?

Comment: not sure what a form helper is i am fresh off Active record and ruby and I am coming into the rails world trying to figure this out.

Comment: Show your routes file. Also you spelled destroy *destory* .

Comment: you don't need a form, just create a link with `link_to` helper using method delete.

Comment: @Maxence - Great point! And true. I was so thrown by that mash up that I was disoriented.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your routes set up correctly, you should be doing something like:

```
<%= form_for @question, method: :delete do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You should NOT be crafting that HTML by hand.

You really need to read the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and the [api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) (scroll down to "form_for with a model object").

Comment: I couldn't get this to work if you could go into some detail to help me that would be awesome!

Comment: Update your question with what you tried. And any errors you got in console.